# How do I address the error for the expression I have created within Cognos Report Studio

Tags: cognos

```
CASE ?choice?
WHEN 1 THEN([Sales (query)].[Time (ship date)].[Date (ship date)] in_range ?Date?)
WHEN 2 THEN [Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method code] = ?OrderMethod?
 ELSE [Sales (query)].[Employee by region].[Employee key] = ?Employee?
END



QE-DEF-0459  CCLException
QE-DEF-0260 Parsing error before or near position: 162 of: Case ?choice?
WHEN 1 THEN([Sales (query)].[Time (ship date)].[Date (ship date)] in_range ?Date?)
WHEN 2 THEN [Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method code] = ?OrderMethod?
QE-DEF-0261 QFWP - Parsing text: CASE ?choice?
```

Comment: Is this in a filter or a data item expression?  May not matter.  Every path of your `CASE` statement must return data of a type.  An expression that returns a boolean (like a = b) is not valid.  Rather than "fix my code", how about providing some information about what you are trying to accomplish?  And what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I think what Cognos is complaining about is the `=`  at `[Order method code] = ?OrderMethod?`.  That's around position 162.

Comment: What version of Cognos and what version of the samples data are you using?  I don't see `Employee by region` in `Sales (query)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's several errors actually.

The one which is complained about is that your choice prompt is in the wrong place.  Once you get over that you will need to deal with a few missing parentheses

CASE
WHEN
(?choice?= 1 )
THEN
([Sales (query)].[Time (ship date)].[Date (ship date)] in_range ?Date?)
WHEN
(?choice?= 2)
THEN
( [Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method code] = ?OrderMethod?)
ELSE
( [Sales (query)].[Employee by region].[Employee key] = ?Employee?)
END

[image]

Comment: I understand that some RDBMSs don't like the style of `CASE` statement in the OP, but that doesn't appear to be the main problem.  Your answer still appears to have the same problem that the OP has -- the case statement doesn't return data.  The additional parentheses don't appear to add any value.

Comment: I have found that CASE WHEN (  ) THEN (   ) makes sure that the expression is parsed without ambiguity.   I only executed the prompt, which gets the guy over the hump.  I didn't fill in values.  Other stuff, such as whether he would really want a prompt page or cascading prompts is up to him.

Answer (score 0):

Good question,

Did some testing

Example 1 will work

```
CASE ?choice?
WHEN 1 THEN([Data Item abc] =1)
WHEN 2 THEN ([Data Item xyz] =2)
 ELSE ([Something Else] =3)
END
```

Example 2 will show errors because of the missing parenthesis (see the second when statement)

```
CASE ?choice?
WHEN 1 THEN([Data Item abc] =1)
WHEN 2 THEN [Data Item xyz] =2
 ELSE ([Something Else] =3)
END
```

Using your example,

```
CASE ?choice?
WHEN 1 THEN ([Sales (query)].[Time (ship date)].[Date (ship date)] in_range ?Date?)
WHEN 2 THEN ([Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method code] = ?OrderMethod?)
 ELSE ([Sales (query)].[Employee by region].[Employee key] = ?Employee?)
END
```

You may want to try a filter like this, just to troubleshoot:

```
(?choice? = 1 AND 
  [Sales (query)].[Time (ship date)].[Date (ship date)] in_range ?Date?) OR 
(?choice? = 2 AND 
  [Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method code] = ?OrderMethod?) OR 
(?choice? <> 1 AND ?choice? <> 2 AND 
  [Sales (query)].[Employee by region].[Employee key] = ?Employee?)
```

Comment: Glad to hear!   Can you flag my answer as helpful?